# How to get users to accept terms before they log in?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So basically I am making some changes to my site to protect me legally. From now on before people are able to register they must tick a box that states that they accept our terms of service.
However as for the existing users apart from a part in our terms of service that says by connecting to our site they accept our terms of service, they don't physically have to click or accept anything. What I was thinking however is that maybe I could after they login have a script that checks whether or not in the database they have accepted the terms of service or not. If they haven't checked it they will be directed to a page where they are displayed the terms of service and connect it. On this page it will update the field in the database saying that "yes they have accepted the terms". For users that have accepted the terms they will be logged in normally.
Anyway, basically what I am asking is; is this the best way to go about things and how exactly would I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show here your login part code

Comment: Do you use a php framework? Could you show us your php code? Nevertheless, you have descibed what to do successfully.

Comment: Why you don't put a plain "by signing up you accept the Terms of Use blah blah" message on the registration page? IMHO having to click and accept each time I log in is _rather_ annoying. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: The purpose of this is to make users accept it once, then it will detect that they have accepted it and they will not have to do it again. What I want to know is what sort of script would I need for this? Would it be something like "if $query = 'Accepted' - let them log in; else - make them register"?